# Reading from the Istream, how to first read one word then an entire line, and return it?

Tags: c++, stream, getline, istream, extraction-operator

I have the following struct:

```
struct Person{
   std::string name;
   std::string address;

   std::string& personName(){ return name; }
   std::string& personAddress(){return address;}
};
```

The exercise is to write a read function that will read name and address. For example, the function I first wrote was this:

```
std::istream &read(std::istream &is, Person &person){
    is >> person.name >> person.address;
    return is;
}
```

However this function fails to take more than a word for `address`. For example if input is:

> Lee Goswell Road

The output will be `person.name` = "Lee" and `person.address` = "Goswell". What I want is the function to read the entire address basically. I did try solving this problem as follows, but I am not sure it is right because address is changed implicitly:

```
std::istream &read(std::istream &is, Person &person){
    is >> person.name;
    std::getline(std::cin, person.address);
    return is;
}
```

Another thing to consider before saying I should write separate functions, the task is to write one function to take read both the name and address.

Comment: `std::getline(is, person.address)`. However, `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max, '\n')` if you're going to mix `operator>>` and `std::getline`.

Comment: @remyabel I'm trying to understand what the motivation of the `ignore` is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `operator>>` in tandem with `std::getline` but you'll probably want to eat the white-space from the stream first.

Also rather than `read`, you should just create your own `operator>>`:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Person& person){
    is >> person.name >> std::ws;
    std::getline(is, person.address);
    return is;
}
```

You can then use this as follows:

```
std::istringstream foo("Lee Goswell Road\nJon Lois Lane");
Person bar;

foo >> bar;

std::cout << bar.name << std::endl << bar.address << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read a word, skip leading whitespace, then read to a delimiter:

```
if (is >> person.name >> std::ws
    std::getline(is, person.address)) {
    // do something with the input
}
else {
    // deal with input failure
}
```

`std::ws` simply skips leading whitespace and `std::getline()` reads to delimiter with `'\n'` being the default.

Comment: If I use the above. When I type return 'is', will the input from getline also be returned by the function? Sorry, if this is a rudimentary question, I am having a bit of trouble understanding how the iostreams work.

Comment: @WalidBeydoun Think of `is` as being a string with a caret somewhere telling the stream it's current position. This code will update that caret position. Returning `is` is key though for chaining operators, not necessary in your `read` function but my `operator>>` must return `std::istream&` so that you can do something like this: `foo >> person1 >> person2 >> person3;` each operator is using the returned stream from the previous operator.